# One mantra for praising all deities of three Lokas

Tags: gods, mantras

Each and every god/deities having corresponding mantras itself. However Lord Paramesvara said in Vishnu Saharanamam the most valuable and powerful mantra to be chanted is:

> ईश्वर उवाच
>   श्रीराम राम रामेती रमे रामे मनोरमे ।
>   सहस्रनाम तत्तुल्यं रामनाम वरानने ॥27 ॥
>
> ishwara uvAcha:
>   sri rAma rAma rAmethi rame rAme manorame |
>   sahasranAma thatthulyam rAma nAma varAnane |

But my question is, what is the mantra (only one mantra) if I going to chant and get blessing from all deities (*in three worlds swargaloka, bhooloka, pathalaloka*) and satisfy them.

Comment: Aum or om would be that mantra. Or else.some mantras of vedic samhitas would be of that idea

Comment: Further gayatri is general purpose mantra and is considered the most important of all vedic mantras

Comment: @RakeshJoshi, pranava and gayatri mantra are not for distribution without qualification.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There technically is "no only one mantra" if you're planning to please all the deities in the Triloka. But there are alternatives. If you wish to get the mantra which all the gods adhere to and pay allegiance, but non-Vedantic - then try the Gayatri Mantra. It is present in many sources, however I am taking it from the Surya Upanishad.

**Surya Upanishad** Verse 3

> **Aum bhūr-bhuva̱ḥ-suva̍ḥ |
>  tat sa̍vi̱tur vare̎ṇya̱m bhargo de'vasya
>   dh'īmahi |
>  dhiyo̱ yo na̍ḥ praco̱dayā̎t ||**
>
> Om, Earth, middle region and sky; we meditate on the adorable splendor
>   of Savitar (Sun) who may inspire our thoughts.

Vishnu and Shiva mantras are generally favoured if you want direct blessings from every god out there.

> **Om Namo Bhagavate Vasudevaya.**
>
> **Om Namo Bhagavate Rudraya.**

These mantras are invoked at the beginning of many Puranas and stotras.

If you want an all encompassing Gayatri for deities combined in a single flow you can refer to Mahanarayana Upanishad and keep on chanting all the Gayatris.

Mahanarayana Upanishad

> **purushasya vidmahe sahasrakshasya mahadevasya dhimahi | tannorudrah
>   pracodayat || 22||
>
> tatpurushaya vidmahe mahadevaya dhimahi | tanno
>   rudrah pracodayat || 23||
>
> tatpurushaya vidmahe vakratundaya dhimahi
>   | tanno dantih pracodayat || 24||
>
> tatpurushaya vidmahe cakratundaya
>   dhimahi | tanno nandih pracodayat || 25||
>
> tatpurushaya vidmahe
>   mahasenaya dhimahi | tannah shanmukhah pracodayat ||
>   26||
>
> tatpurushaya vidmahe suvarnapakshaya dhimahi | tanno garudah
>   pracodayat || 27||
>
> vedatmanaya vidmahe hiranyagarbhaya dhimahi |
>   tanno brahma pracodayat || 28||
>
> narayanaya vidmahe vasudevaya
>   dhimahi | tanno vishnuh pracodayat || 29||
>
> vajranakhaya vidmahe
>   tikshnadam shtraya dhimahi | tannonarasim hah pracodayat || 30||
>
>
>   bhaskaraya vidmahe mahaddyutikaraya dhimahi | tanno adityyah
>   pracodayat || 31||
>
> vaishvanaraya vidmahe lalilaya dhimahi | tanno
>   agnih pracodayat || 32||
>
> katyayanaya vidmahe kanyakumari dhimahi |
>   tanno durgih pracodayat || 33||
>
> pathabhedahcaturmukhaya vidmahe
>   kamandaludharaya dhimahi | tanno brahma pracodayat ||
>
> adityaya
>   vidmahe sahasrakiranaya dhimahi | tanno bhanuh pracodayat
>   ||
>
> pavakaya vidmahe saptajihvaya dhimahi | tanno vaishvanarah
>   pracodayat ||
>
> mahashulinyai vidmahe mahadurgayai dhimahi | tanno
>   bhagavati pracodayat ||
>
> subhagayai vidmahe kamalamalinyai dhimahi |
>   tanno gauri pracodayat ||
>
> navakulaya vidmahe vishadantaya dhimahi |
>   tannah sarpah pracodayat ||**

If you're looking for a deity-less all encompassing mantra, there is only ONE and ONE only:

> **AUM - ॐ**

Comment: Swargaloka, Bhuloka and Patala exist in this material world. If you are aiming for Moksha (liberation) you don’t need the grace of beings in these three worlds. Secondly, as mentioned by Arkaprabha, there is no ONE mantra...

Comment: @HayagreevRam how many times is moksha or mukti mentioned in vedas.?

Comment: @RakeshJoshi The concept of Moksha is mentioned mostly in the Upanishads, which are considered to be a part of the Vedas. Not sure as to how many times it is mentioned...

Comment: @HayagreevRam ok when you have time go through my post on upanishad and Vedas.

Comment: @RakeshJoshi But where can I find them??

Answer (score 1):

The Gayatri Mantra is only for the brahmins who have been initiated properly as per our scriptures. This I found in Writings of Sri Sitaramdas Omkarnath, a famous saint from Bengal.

The following mantra which is there in so many puja books is beautiful:

> प्रीयतां पुण्डरीकाक्ष सर्वयज्ञेश्वरो हरिः।
> तस्मिन् तुष्टे जगत् तुष्टं प्रीणीते प्रीणितं जगत्॥
>   
>  Translation: May Lotus-eyed Hari, who is the Lord of all divine activities or sacrifices be pleased. If He is satisfied, all is satisfied. If He is pleased, all is pleased.

The Gitaprasasti also says: सर्वदेवमयो हरिः meaning that Hari is the abode of all gods.

So I think the above mantra can praise all deities.

Comment: not only brahmins but anyone who is having upanayana or sacred thread can do it. it includes other varnas too..

Comment: The gayatris of kshatriyas and vaishyas are slightly different so far as i know

Comment: You can reply to a specific user by writing @ before their username. @ParthaBanerjee

Comment: @KrishnaShweta thnx

Comment: @ParthaBanerjee no difference.

Answer (score 1):

Ram naam is the only mantra by which all the deities are pleased.

सर्वे अवताराः श्री राम नाम शक्ति समुद्भवाः।

Skandpuran

Mahadev says: All avtars of Vishnu are originated from shri ram naam.

Also

सर्वेषाम अवताराणां कारणं परमद्भुतम्।

श्रीमद्रामेति नामेव कथ्यते सद्भिरनवहम्।।
Vayupuran

All avtars of Vishnu have originated from shri ram

असंख्य पुण्यनिश्चैः कोटिजन्मार्जित अपि।

पंचागोपसनाभिश्च रामनाम्नि रतिर्भवेत्।।
Bhusundi Ramayan

After getting unlimited virtues through Panchang upasana for crore of births, one gets Ram bhakti ( love of Ram naam)

रा शक्तिः इति विख्याता मः शिवः परिकीर्तितः।

शिव शक्ति आत्मकं ब्रह्म राम रामेति गीयते।।
Jarakhya samhita

Ra---> shakti
M ---> shiv
Ram mean shakti and shiv both

नायनाय यद्दतेऽक्षराष्टिकं च न शिवाय यद्विना।

मुक्तिदं भवति यद्वयोर्वशात्तद् द्वयं वयमुपास्महे किल।।
Shuka samhita

If we omit "ra" from narayanaya, it becomes ineffective. And if we omit "m" From namah shivay, it also ineffective. So to get moksh one should chant "ram".

रामनाम्नः समुत्पन्नो प्रणव मोक्षदायकः।
Maha ramayan

Ram naam is even the originator of pranav ie (ऊं)

श्रीरामस्मरेणैनैव नरो यान्ति परांगतिम्।

सत्यं सत्यं सदा सत्यम्  न जाने नामजं फलम्।।

श्रीरामके स्मरण करने से ही मनुष्य परमगतिको प्राप्त हो जाता है; यह बात सत्य है, सत्य है और शाश्वतिक ( सदा ) सत्य है; राम नाम जपके फलकी महिमाको मैं भी नहीं जानता हूँ उसका वर्णन करना मेरे लिए भी कठिन है ।
(आदि पुराण~ श्रीकृष्ण अर्जुन संवाद)

Answer (score 1):

**श्रीकृष्ण उवाच~युधिष्ठिर के प्रति**

*मंत्रा नानाविधाः सन्ति शतशो राघवस्य च।
तेभ्यस्त्वेकं वदाम्यद्य तव मंत्रं युधिष्ठिर।।
श्रीशब्धमाद्य जयशब्दमध्यंजयद्वेयेनापि पुनःप्रयुक्तम्।
अनेनैव च मन्त्रेण जपः कार्यः सुमेधसा।*

( श्रीमद् वाल्मीकियानंद रामायण, 9~7.44,45a,46a)

हे युधिष्ठिर! वैसे तो श्रीराघाव के अनेक मन्त्र हैं, किन्तु उनमें से एक उत्तम मन्त्र मैं तुमको बतलाता हूँ । पूर्वमें श्रीराम शब्द, मध्यमें जय शब्द और अन्तमें दो जय शब्दोंसे मिला हुआ (श्रीराम जय राम जय जय राम) राममन्त्र। बुद्धिमान जनों को सिर्फ इसी मंत्र का जाप करना चाहिए।

Comment: Please post in an universal language.

Comment: Shri krishna says to yudhishthir that ram naam is the greatest mantra that can give both moksh and wealth

Comment: It's good if the answer is posted in English